# Qt on Mac 10.11: code has no resources but signature indicates they must be present

Tags: macos, qt, sparkle

I have a Qt 5.4 application with Sparkle framework. Gatekeeper on Mac OS X 10.11 will display "unidentified developer" error after downloading from our server. After some researches (codesign --strict shows missing file in sparkle), I removed broken symbolic links in Sparkle framework. Then I rebuilt the app, the check with both codesign and spctl

codesign --verbose --deep --strict myapp.app

The result is:
myapp.app: satisfies its Designated Requirment

spctl --assess --type exec --verbose myapp.app
shows: accepted

next I built dmg image, install from image, the app runs without issue.
Then I uploaded dmg to server, and downloaded from our server. MD5 checksum matches.

However, after I drag and drop the app to /Applications folder, ran it, OS shows the application is corrupted and must be moved to trash.The same codesign command still returns "Satifies its Designated Requirements", but the same spctl command shows:

code has no resources but signature indicates they must be present

Just by downloading the app from our server, spctl output changed. I don't think it has anything to do with resources (the app does have resources) since the same build script has created a few releases without this error. the script does modify qt framework structure but that works on 10.10.

I built a new Mac OS 10.11, installed xcode 7.0.1, Qt 5.5, rebuilt the app (without the script to modify Qt framework structure in App bundle). Exact the same result: the app passes both codesign and spctl before upload, and failed with the same error after downloading.

In essence, after removing broken link in Sparkle framework, the app bundle changed from "unidentified developer" to "corrupted image".

Can someone tell me where it went wrong?

Comment: I've seen a similar issue in the past, which turned out to be a problem of a server zipping an app bundle and copying files instead of maintaining symbolic links. Check that your app is intact, especially any symbolic links. It sounds like the app bundle has been changed somewhere along the line.

Comment: This morning, I rebooted the Mac OS X 10.11, and noticed spctl output changed to "accepted". To make sure I didn't accidentally changed something on my side, I rebuilt the app bundle, re-upload and download, repeated twice, the result is good: "accepted". At this point, it seems there is nothing wrong on my side.

Comment: Great. If all is well, then I suggest deleting the question, as it doesn't add anything of value to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Agree! or please mention in the answer that what extra you did to resolve the problem.